# Rails dockerization: any advice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpacker

I followed https://medium.com/soulmates-ai/running-a-rails-app-with-webpacker-and-docker-8d29153d3446 to adapt my Rails project to Docker, using Webpacker and Rails as separate services.

As a noob, I would be very glad to anyone who could give me some time to review these lines, and tell me if I'm doing it correctly :)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.5-slim

ARG PRECOMPILEASSETS
ARG RAILS_ENV

ENV RAILS_ENV ${RAILS_ENV}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN curl -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get -y update && \
      apt-get install --fix-missing --no-install-recommends -qq -y \
        build-essential \
        vim \
        wget gnupg \
        git-all \
        curl \
        ssh \
        postgresql-client-10 libpq5 libpq-dev -y && \
      wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x  | bash - && \
      apt-get install -y nodejs && \
      wget -qO- https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
      echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
      apt-get update && \
      apt-get install yarn && \
      apt-get clean && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN gem install bundler
#Install gems
RUN mkdir /gems
WORKDIR /gems
COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install


ARG INSTALL_PATH=/opt/beweeg
ENV INSTALL_PATH $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY . .

# Precompile assets (or not)
RUN docker/potential_asset_precompile.sh $PRECOMPILEASSETS
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  webpacker:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME-beweeg}
    command: ["./docker/start_webpack_dev.sh"]
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/beweeg:cached
    ports:
      - 3035:3035

  app:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME-beweeg}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PRECOMPILEASSETS=NO
        - RAILS_ENV=development
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - APP_HOST=localhost:3000
      - SMTP_USERNAME
      - SMTP_PWD
      - SMTP_DOMAIN
      - SMTP_ADDRESS
      - SMTP_PORT
      - SMTP_AUTHENTICATION
      - SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO
    links:
      - db
      - webpacker
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: ["./docker/wait_for_it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "./docker/start_rails.sh"]
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/beweeg:cached
```

**.dockerignore**

```
.git
.gitignore
*.md
.dockerignore
.gitlab-ci.yml
docker-compose.*
Dockerfile
log/*
node_modules/*
public/assets/*
storage/*
public/js/*
public/js-test/*
tmp/*
```

The rest should be quite the same as in the related article from Soulmates... What do you think?
NB: The project is private, that's why I can't share it entirely... sorry for that. If more sources are needed please tell me and I'll try to make a demo fake project :)

Thx in advance

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: Nope, it's just the will to learn and to things correctly 